# count the no of sundays between two dates in db2

Tags: java, db2

I have two dates in my code..date 1 and date2.
I want to calculate the number of sundays between the above dates,
I am using IBM DB2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: used Google ever ? http://bit.ly/GCpgVB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you mean in your code.

If you have values you're trying to lookup from a database the most sustainable way would be to create a function that you could call.  If this is not doable as a result of your permissions / etc. you can take a look at the below SQL:

```
WITH DATE_EXAMPLES (DATE_1, DATE_2) AS (
    VALUES ( TIMESTAMP('2012-03-04 01:01:01'),TIMESTAMP('2012-03-25 01:01:01'))
)
SELECT  DATE_EXAMPLES.*, 
    CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(DATE_2) < DAYOFWEEK(DATE_1) 
            THEN    ((DAYS(DATE_2) - DAYS(DATE_1)) / 7) + 1
            ELSE    ((DAYS(DATE_2) - DAYS(DATE_1)) / 7)
    END SUNDAYS_BETWEEN        
FROM DATE_EXAMPLES
```

*Please note: The `DAYOFWEEK` call will return a number `range of 1-7` where 1 is Sunday and 7 is Saturday.